# Python read() if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file to check if the content is a 0 or a 1 with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

file = open('test', 'r')

read=file.read()

if read == 2:
        print "do something"
else:   print "do something else"
```

But the output of the file is always "do something else" even if the file contains a 2.

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `read` is an int and not a string? Try `read = int(file.read().strip())`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are comparing a string with an int `read == 2`. That's gonna always return false. Also, take into account possible line endings and watch your indentation. Code should be like this:

```
file = open('test', 'r')

read=file.read().rstrip('\n')   # removes possible line endings

if read == '2':
    print "do something"
else:
    print "do something else"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that won't raise an unhandled exception when the file contents isn't a number

Answer (score 1):

`file.read()` returns a string. If there is just 2 in the file you need to convert it to `int`:

```
read = int(file.read())
```

Or do a string check instead:

```
if read == '2':
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a line you read from a file (that is, a string) to an integer. Try the following:

```
if int(read.strip()) == 2:
    print "Hello!"
```